# how to print the content of a text file in c

Tags: c, file, text, while-loop, fgets

Iam trying to print the content of a text file called text.txt in the terminal in c I have the following code but it doesn't work:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
int main(){
 char str[255];
 FILE *fp;
 fp = fopen("text.txt","r");
 while (fgets(str,255,fp)!=NULL){
    printf("%s",str);
    fclose(fp);
 };
}
```

I couldn't find a solution please help

Comment: Please describe in excruciating detail what it does _instead of_ working.  There are several different things that could have gone wrong here and we have no way of knowing which.  (I can tell you right now, though, that the call to `fclose(fp)` almost certainly should not be inside the while loop.)

Comment: Move the call to `fclose` to a point after the `while` loop finishes. It doesn't make sense to close the file within the body of the loop.

Comment: You should check that `fopen()` succeeds before using the value in `fp`.  You should only close the file stream when you've finished reading the whole file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you are closing the file inside the loop. `fclose` should lie at the end of your program. Secondly, `fopen()` might fail (you don't have permission to read the file for example). So, don't forget to handle that too.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(){
    const int sz = 255;

    char str[sz];
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("input.txt","r");
    if(fp == NULL){
        // opening the file failed ... handle it
    }
    while (fgets(str,sz,fp)!=NULL){
        printf("%s",str);
    };

    fclose(fp);
}
```

Here is another similar way

```
  if (fp!=NULL)
  {
    // file open succeded. do sth with it.
    fclose (fp);
  }
```

Hope this helps and keep coding!

Comment: `nullptr` is c++, not c

Comment: Nit.. Better `fputs (str, stdout);`, there is no conversion requiring `printf()` (though a good compiler will make that substitution for you)